# Expected hexadecimal on javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex, backbone.js

While solving an issue in aspx, I got stuck while setting a backbone property from the ASP.Net session variable.

I want to set a property with value that contains '\u' in character in between. Like

```
  App.prop.set("Username",<%= Session.Name %>)
```

Session.Name contains "john\udenver" as value, When I put debugger in javascript and check the value it has escaped \u correctly as "john\udenver"

So Session.Name already has the escaped value of "john\udenver".

But when it renders and trying to assign the value to property, it is unescaping \u and I get an exception saying "Error:Expected hexadecimal digit."

I tried to escape using "escape" method

```
App.prop.set("Username", escape ("<%= Session.Name %>"))
```

but it throws same exception, it renders as

```
App.prop.set("Username", escape ("john\udenver"))
```

I think while rendering the page it gets changed to "john\udenver" and throws the exception.

One of the workarounds can be to put RegEx check before <%= Session.Name %>.

```
App.Prop.set("Username","<%= System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Escape(Session.Name)%>");
```

But this does not seem to be the cleanest of ways. 
Need help to set and get this property in the page with \u or \x present in the string. Can you please suggest.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Well first of all using `\u` outside of a Unicode escape sequence, or `\x` outside of a hexadecimal escape is disallowed by the specification, and causes some engines to throw a syntax error. Accordingly `"john\udenver"` is an illegal string in JS since obviously the engine is looking for an unicode character after `\u` and a failure will result a syntax error.

```
UnicodeEscapeSequence ::
u HexDigit HexDigit HexDigit HexDigitIn
```

so instead of an HexDigit it finds denver.

So if the `Session.Name` value is already `"john\udenver"` make sure to escape the backslash with another one like

```
App.prop.set("Username",<%= Session.Name.replace(/\\(?=[ux])/g, "\\\\") %>)
```